# How to prepare a solution of Ferrous Iron?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, aqueous-solution, iron

I need to prepare a solution of Ferrous Iron (Fe2+). This solution will be used to test a water filtration system by simulating the Ferrous Iron that is sometimes present in well water. The system is supposed to convert the Ferrous Iron to Iron Hydroxide precipitate via a Manganese Oxide catalyst and filter it out.

What is the best way to get the Iron 2+ ions into the solution? I have seen suggestions to add Iron(II) Sulfate or Mohr's Salt. Something that is confusing me is that the Wikipedia articles for these compounds suggest they form a complex when dissolved in water. For Iron(II) Sulfate and Mohrs Salt the aquo complex [Fe(H2O)6]2+ is formed. I am wondering, are Iron(II) ions always in this aquo complex, and perhaps in some discussions of chemistry this fact is ignored for simplification? I question if the Iron 2+ ion will be available to participate in the reactions and get converted to Iron Hydroxide if it is in the aquo complex.

To summarize, what is the best way to make a solution with Fe 2+ ions that will simulate well water? And an explanation of the chemistry of the aquo complex formed by Mohrs salt and Iron(II) Sulfate and how that differs or is the same as a Fe 2+ ion alone in solution would be appreciated if someone is so inclined.

Thank you for sharing your knowledge!

Comment: Have you searched the literature? Certainly, there must be previous examples. You are right, it is $\ce{[Fe(H2O)6]^{2+}}$. Consider it synonymous with $\ce{Fe^{2+}}$.

Comment: If you got your answer, feel free to self answer it. Self-answers are appreciated and it also helps future readers.